# How to convert link.php?id=# to the actual url behind it? [web crawling]

Tags: php, python, web-crawler

I want to create a web crawler that start at a certain website that contains a lot of link to other websites on it (since it is a good starting point for my purposes) and visit each website, and so on, using a BFS algorithm. However, most of the links on this website have the following relative addresses: `/link.php?id=some_number` that points to an external website. Since I have to add them to a list of visited websites (for the BFS), how can I convert this code to a normal URL (i.e. the absolute address behind this code), unless there's a better way to do this? I'm using python with `BeautifulSoup` and the `requests` library.

Comment: Can't you prepend the URI of the page currently being crawled?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: If the page you're currently crawling is "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" and the link you're seeing is "/question.php?id=some_number", then the full link is "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" + "/question.php?id=some_number", or "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/question.php?id=some_number". [Note: StackOverflow adds a bunch of semicolons in there. None of them should be there but I can't remove them via the editor. Weird.]

Comment: I should probably edit my question. By URI I meant the thing after the www.stackoverflow.com/. The relative address if you will. I want to convert the link.php thing to the actual address it's pointing to (which is a completely separate website).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now- these links redirect to some external site, and you want to get that instead?

Comment: Exactly. I thinks it's more understandable now I've edited it

Comment: you can follow the link and the site will redirect you ... however there is nothing saying id=1 will always point to the same resource.,.. just thats what it is pointing to now